Maildev starts without CSS and JS in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 Ootpa
I use putty to acces to remote VM for my php project and i want to install maidev
whoami :  root
OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 Ootpa
trace:

npm install -g maildev

npm list -g maildev =>  /root/.nvm/versions/node/v22.2.0/lib
└── maildev@2.1.0


the maildev folder is in :  /root/.nvm/versions/node/v22.2.0/lib/node_modules/maildev :
the maildev folder contain :



-index.js




-app/ --


scripts/


styles



MailDev webapp running at http://0.0.0.0:1080/
MailDev SMTP Server running at 0.0.0.0:1025
appache file :
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DocumentRoot "/var/www/groomrhv2/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/groomrhv2/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.php

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Require all granted
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</FilesMatch>

# Proxy configuration for MailDev web interface
ProxyPass "/maildev" "http://127.0.0.1:1080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/maildev" "http://127.0.0.1:1080/"

when i start the projet on xxxxxx:/maildev  i get in console

GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
maildev:163


Blockquote GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
maildev:165


Blockquote GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
maildev:162


Blockquote

GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/components/angular/angular.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
maildev:9

Blockquote

GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/styles/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
